# C++ equivalent to Python's cmp or Haskell's compare

Tags: c++, python, haskell

**Question:**

Is there a C++ equivalent for Python's `cmp` or Haskell's `compare`?

`compare` is like `operator==` and `operator<` in one. It returns `LT`, `EQ`, or `GT`. But it's twice as fast as calling both `operator==` and `operator<` because it does it in one pass.

**More details:**

At work, I often have structs that are used as keys for maps, for example:

```
struct RecordUsedAsAKey {
    int field_a;
    string field_b;
    vector<float> field_c;

    // operator< is needed for keys in maps.
    bool operator<(const RecordUsedAsAKey& other) const;
};

bool RecordUsedAsAKey::operator<(const RecordUsedAsAKey& other) const {
    if (field_a != other.field_a)
        return field_a < other.field_a;
    if (field_b != other.field_b)
        return field_b < other.field_b;
    return field_c < other.field_c;
}
```

One problem with `RecordUsedAsAKey::operator<` is that it's unnecessarily slow.

- When the `string::operator!=` finds a different character, the program iterates over the equal characters again in the `string::operator<`, when it could have skipped those..
- Same for the `vector`'s comparison.

If I had an equivalent to Haskell's `compare`, my comparison method would had been more efficient:

```
Ordering RecordUsedAsAKey::compare(const RecordUsedAsAKey& other) const {
    Ordering t;
    if ((t = field_a.compare(other.field_a)) != EQ)
        return t;
    if ((t = field_b.compare(other.field_b)) != EQ)
        return t;
    return field_c.compare(other.field_c);
}
```

This is more efficient because the `string`'s `compare` method does only one pass on the string.

Btw/mini-flame-war: in Haskell the whole code for the comparison would just be `deriving Ord`.

Comment: Why don't you just write your own in C++?

Comment: @David Heffernan: I may revert to that, but I'd much rather use an existing function than writing and maintaining my own. Using an existing one would mean less bugs, less work for me and less work for the readers of my code.

Comment: the list of C++ operators is well defined. This one isn't in it.

Comment: @David Heffernan: It doesn't have to be an operator, named functions are as good. Being not defined doesn't mean that boost or some other library doesn't provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily implement it yourself, as a free function.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
enum order {
    order_lt = -1,
    order_eq,
    order_gt
};

// General case, templated version.
template < typename T >
order compare(T left, T right) {
    if (left < right)
        return order_lt;
    if (left == right)
        return order_eq;
    return order_gt;
}

// Specialization
order compare(const std::string& left, const std::string& right) {
    return order(left.compare(right));
}
template < typename T >
order compare(const std::vector<T>& left, const std::vector<T>& right) {
     order o = compare(left.size(), right.size());
     if (o != order_eq)
         return o;
     for (size_t i = 0; i < left.size(); ++ i) {
         o = compare(left[i], right[i]);
         if (o != order_eq)
             return o;
     }
     return order_eq;
}
```

Note: I edited the code to include a templated version for the general case (work provided that the operator< and operator== are defined for the type). I also kept some specialization as it can improve run time on some type (mainly containers).

Edit: Using `std::string::compare` instead of `strcmp`.

Comment: The templates for comparing `string`s and `vector`s look useful for writing something specific for the `RecordUsedAsAKey` type. However there only needs to be one completely unspecialized template for all other types (including `int` and `float`) that can be compared and therefore follow the pattern shown that they all have.

Comment: I suppose one would want to add an unspecialized template like martineau suggested. In that case I think it would have to be a `static` method of a class as C++ doesn't allow partial function template specialization (needed for vector).

Comment: @yairchu: There is no need of partial specialization, we can use overriding, can't we ?

Comment: std::string already has a compare member function. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since `map` semantics are in term of `operator<`, and that in fact many operators implementations are in term of `operator<`, probably something only in term of it is better.

For instance:

```
template <typename T>
int compare(const T& x, const T& y)
{
    if (x < y) return -1;
    else if (y < x) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

or, better,

```
template <typename T, typename F>
int compare(const T& x, const T& y, F pred)
{
    if (pred(x, y)) return -1;
    else if (pred(y, x)) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

template <typename T>
int compare(const T& x, const T& y)
{
    return compare(x, y, std::less<T>());
}
```

so that you can use `compare(k1, k2, mymap.key_comp())` if you need to.

After your program works, **and you are convinced that `compare` is the bottleneck**, you can specialize for the offending types. Do for instance

```
template <typename C, typename T, typename A>
int compare(const std::basic_string<C, T, A>& x,
            const std::basic_string<C, T, A>& y)
{
    return x.compare(y);
}
```

if you are worried about efficiency for string types.

If you are comparing sequences, you can use [`std::lexicographical_compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/). However, you may want to reimplement it to handle the equality case, here is an optimized version for `std::vector`:

```
template <typename T, typename A, typename F>
int compare(const std::vector<T, A>& x,
            const std::vector<T, A>& y, F pred)
{
    std::vector<T, A>::const_iterator i = x.begin();
    std::vector<T, A>::const_iterator j = y.begin();

    while (i != x.end())
    {
        if (j == y.end()) return 1;
        if (pred(*i, *j)) return -1
        else if (pred(*j, *i)) return 1;

        ++i; ++j;
    }

    return j == y.end() ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simpler and more general version of Sylvain Defresne's answer:

```
template<typename T>
order compare(const T &left, const T &right) {
    if (left < right)
        return order_lt;
    else if (left == right)
        return order_eq;
    return order_gt;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it does not optimise the comparison by only iterating once on `string`, `vector`, ... Maybe by using some overriding, the two solution can be merged, to use the templated version for simple types, and to use a specialized version for string, vector, ... that only iterator once.

Answer (score 1):

The std::string already has a compare member function that does what you want.

For other sequences, like std::vector, there is a std::mismatch function in `<algorithm>` that scans two sequences side-by-side and returns iterators to the first two elements that differ. From there, you only have to figure out if these two elements are less than or greater than each other.